# Scoring script in Python

Tags: python

Phyton beginner here!

I'm trying to score values in a table column based on a set of conditions (like if the value is between x and y then score z). I have a matrix with the scores and would like to avoid a whole lot of "ifs" in my code as I have a bunch of columns with different sets to score. Any ideas how to simplify this?

Thanks!

Comment: Hello, welcome to SO. I am sure we have a lot of ideas to help you but this question is too broad and will probably be closed. There is no code and there is no MRE. Please refer to the [help](www.stackoverflow.com/help/asking) so you can come back with an appropriate question.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO, please provide what you have been tried, and a sample of your matrix to make us be able to help you

Comment: "Based on a set of conditions".. How can we advise you when we don't know a single condition nor the original start input to begin with?

Comment: How about making a sorted matrix of triples `(x, y, z)` then if for each `w` if it's between `x_i, y_i` you can find it by `O(log n)` and then add the score `z_i`

Comment: Also providing an example or code would be great actually